# Example for Union of Countably infinite closed sets being closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am not able to find a single interval example for the above.
For example can someone help me write the interval $[0,1]$ as a union of countably infinite closed sets ? I know it is possible, but I can't seem to figure out a way.

Comment: Do you mean the union of a countably infinite family of closed sets, or do you mean the union of a family of countably infinite closed sets?

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb R$

Comment: @PtF: What element of your union on the right hand side contains $1$, which is an element of the left hand side? For the union to contain $1$, $1$ must be an element of at least one of the sets in the union.

Comment: Right, the correct would be $$[0, 1]=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [0, 1-1/n]\cup \{1\}.,$$

Comment: @PtF however your sets are not countably infinite.

Comment: Does “countably infinite” refer to the cardinality of each of the sets, or to the number of sets in the family whose union you are taking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $0<x\le 1$ let $$A_x=\left\{\frac xn \colon n=1, 2, 3, \ldots\right\}\cup\{0\}.$$
Then every $A_x$ is countably infinite and closed and $[0,1]=\bigcup_{x\in (0,1]} A_x$.

Comment: Also for anyone wondering, the union must involve uncountably many sets because a countable union of countable sets is countable and [0,1] is not countable.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the closed sets to be $[0,\frac{1}{n}]$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then their union, $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [0,\frac{1}{n}] = [0,1]$.

Comment: You miss $1$ in the union, so add $\{1\}$ as another closed set. Moreover, you probably meant $[0,1- \frac{1}{n+1}]$, so a sequence converging to $1$ instead.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma if I put n=1 in my given sequence of closed sets then I get [0,1] so why would I need to add {1} I don't understand. And also I'm not aiming to find a sequence converging to 1. Rest of the answerers have done that so I wanted to answer differently that's why I did the nested interval example.

Comment: boring to have the first set already equal to the union.

Comment: He just asked specifically for the [0,1] to be expressed like this...so I did it in a really simple way as I didn't want to copy other's answers. It's not necessary to complicate things when you can simplify it.

Comment: Hope I'm not seeming rude to you, said all these really normally.

Comment: I just think the OP wanted proper subsets. Or he would have found $F_n=[0,1]$ for all $n$ OK too, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In a metric space any open set is $F_\sigma$, so any infinite closed set can be written as a union of countably many different closed sets (pick a proper closed set and the remainder is $F_\sigma$ by the above). A theorem due to Sierpinski tells us that $[0,1]$ (or any continuum) cannot a *pairwise disjoint* such union, but a union itself is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{q_n\}_{n\in\omega}$ an increasing sequense of rational numbers in $(0,1/2)$ such that $q_n\rightarrow 1/2$. So

$$
[0,1]:=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}[0,q_n]\cup[1/2,1].
$$